# Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY89N.png) when I run my script. (The reason I have so many errors is because I put it in a timer)
My code is:

```
    var ep; // create variable
    var ev; // create variable

    ep.top = $(charct).offset().top;  // get top offset
    ev.left = $(charct).offset().left; // get left offset

    // charct is a div; var charct = document.getElementById('character');
```

I have an idea of what is causing this, (ep and ev are null variables) however, I still do not know how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define variables as `object`

Comment: `var ev = {};` to initialize the variable.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, that worked, i reccomend you make an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can not define properties of `undefined`, create an empty object `{}` and then assign properties over it.

```
var ep = {}; // create variable
var ev = {}; // create variable

ep.top = $(charct).offset().top;  // get top offset
ev.left = $(charct).offset().left; // get left offset
```